# How to change background color of gridview resource in different listviews

Tags: wpf

I have two `ListView`s which use a non-shared `GridView` as their `View`. I have the `GridView` specified in a single place. Is there a way to change the background color of cells for each `GridView` in `ListView` while keeping the rest of the stuff common?

```
...
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="myHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </Style>
    <GridView x:Key="gridview" x:Shared="false" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}">
        <GridView.Columns>
            <GridViewColumn Header="" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Size}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" />
        </GridView.Columns>
    </GridView>
</UserControl.Resources>
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Symbol}" FontSize="14" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Bids}"  View="{DynamicResource gridview}" />
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Offers}" View="{DynamicResource gridview}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can do that but for that you need to **define `CellTemplate` with TextBlock and set background on it** since background property is not exposed for GridViewColumn.

Also you can take advantage of dynamic resources and resource look up behaviour of WPF i.e. resources is searched upwards in logical tree. So, **bind background of TextBlock to some resource key which you can define individually for different ListView under its resources section**.

```
<GridView.Columns>
   <GridViewColumn Header="">
      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Size}"
                      Background="{DynamicResource CellBackgroundColor}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn>
   <GridViewColumn Header="">
      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"
                       Background="{DynamicResource CellBackgroundColor}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn>
</GridView.Columns>
```

Define resource under ListView like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Bids}" View="{DynamicResource gridview}">
     <ListView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CellBackgroundColor" Color="Red"/>
     </ListView.Resources>
  </ListView>
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Offers}" View="{DynamicResource gridview}">
     <ListView.Resources>
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CellBackgroundColor" Color="Yellow"/>
     </ListView.Resources>
  </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```